# how to change the value of the dynamically created button in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, buttonclick, setattribute

Requirements: I have one table with one row and three columns.first column has button ,second column and third column has text box and check box.

if i click that button one new row is added dynamically as same as first row. now if i click the button in newly created row ,one more row should add. as soon as new row added, the current row button should change to delete button.ie only last row button should have add functionality and all other previous row should have delete button .

i wrote some code, hat im getting is, new row is added when i click the last button as well as the previous button..

i want to change the previous dynamically created  button value as delete.while clicking the button,its valuve should change to delete(then this button should able to delete that row) and new row should be added.

please help me to get this output. im trying for long. thank you.

```
<html>

<head runat="server">

<TITLE> Add/Remove dynamic rows in HTML table </TITLE>

<SCRIPT language="javascript">

    function addRow(tableID) {
        var e1=document.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('input');

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);       
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;     
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount); 
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.setAttribute('type','button');
        element1.setAttribute('name','Add Row'+rowCount);
        element1.setAttribute('value','Add Row');               
        cell1.appendChild(element1); 
          element1.setAttribute('onclick','addRow("'+tableID+'")');    
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        element2.type = "text";
        cell2.appendChild(element2);

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var element3 = document.createElement("input");
        element3.type = "checkbox";
        cell3.appendChild(element3);       
     }
</script>

</head>

<BODY>

<TABLE id="dataTable" width="250px" border="1">

<TR>

<td><INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" name="Add Row0" onclick="addRow('dataTable')"/></td>
<TD> <INPUT type="text" /> </TD>

<TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>

</TR>

</TABLE>

</BODY>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you willing to use jQuery for this? The code would be much simpler and shorter to do what you're wanting to do.

Answer (score -1):

If you're willing to use jQuery the answer is this simple:

```
// First clone the last row as a new row
$('#dataTable tr:last-child').clone().appendTo('#dataTable');
// Now change all buttons except the last row to call a delete function
$('#dataTable tr:not(tr:last-child) input[type=button]').click(function (event) {
    // Passing this to the function sends the button element from which you could determine the parent or whatever else you need
    deleteRow(this);
});
```

EDIT:
Also, I would remove the onclick assignment in your HTML if you chose to work this way and instead assign the Add button a .click handler from jQuery:

```
$('#dataTable tr:last-child input[type=button]').click(function (event) {
    addRow('dataTable');
});
```

Comment: do you knw how to do this in javascript. i need to do in javascript. i don knw jquery

Comment: I don't have time at the moment to write it out in Javascript, but if you're willing, learn jQuery. It's not very difficult once you get started and it simplifies so many of these kinds of operations.

Comment: Thank you ... sure i will learn javascript . can you give me some website or book name.. from which i can start learning javascript from basics. i dont knw anything abt javascript.

Comment: Here's a good place to start with jQuery: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp